# How to detect first "/" route call?

Tags: angularjs, url, routes, root, html

Is there anyway to check when `"/"` route is called for the first time?

I mean, check when the home page of the app is opened for the first time.

Comment: do you have a single page app?

Comment: Events on $route like $routeChangeStart can help you.

Comment: @Chandermani yes but how? :( don't you have any clue ?

Comment: $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
   if (next.url = "/")) 
   {

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have an app that is a Single Page Application, if you want code that runs once, use module.run(): http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
  run(function($http /*or whatever*/) { 
     // here goes your code that will only run at module initialization
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cookies. If user visit your app first time then he have not cookies but next time he will have.

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $cookies, $cookieStore, $log) {
    $scope.showHello = !$cookies.visited;
    $cookies.visited = 'yes';
  });
```

view:

```
<div ng-if"showHello">
  Hellow, stranger!
</div>
```

And don't forget to load [ngCookes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) module
    angular.module('App', ['ngCookies']);